# Why does $\sqrt{\frac{x^2-2x+1}{x^2-1}}$ exist at $x = 1$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

So there is this question of the finding domain of the following function:

$\sqrt{\frac{x^2-2x+1}{x^2-1}}$

Through graphing technology, it states that this function is existing at $x = 1$. However, wouldn't that be not possible because of the division by zero in the numerator $x^2-1$? Does the square root affect it in any way? Thanks.

Comment: $\sqrt{\frac{x^2-2x+1}{x^2-1}}$ doesn't "exist" at $x=1$, but $\lim_{x\to1^+}\sqrt{\frac{x^2-2x+1}{x^2-1}}$ does exist.

Comment: Exactly what Shark says. My guess is your graphing software may just be programmed to fill in removable discontinuities, probably by wrongly performing polynomial division before exponentiation, against the usual order of operations, giving you false results.

Comment: Hi, I am using Desmos (online at desmos.com/calculator), and I believe it is a very accurate representation of various kinds function. If you say the right hand side limit exists but not the left, the limit does not exist at all, therefore the limit is not defined.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I have noticed that if you create a table of the function, and have $x = -1$ or  $x = 1$ as the $x$ value it says it is _undefined_, however on the graph there is a solid dot (and not a hole or asymptote)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $x>1$, $f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{x-1}{x+1}}$. Strictly speaking, $f(x)$ is not defined at $1$, but we commonly identify functions with their "maximal continuous extension" like this. In other words we "fill in the holes" that may be present due to domain constraints.

Comment: How would you know which functions it applies to? The one which the factors cancels out from the top and don't create holes?

Comment: Also, it doesn't exist at $x= -1$ because in both the domain constraints the function does not exist?

Comment: @Strikers In general this doesn't really have much to do with algebra, it has to do with any function with a hole in its domain but with a well-defined limit at that point. A common way to construct such functions is to write down functions with a $0/0$ form at a certain point, like here, where cancellation results in a function with a larger domain but which is equal to the given function at all points of the given function's domain. Also yes, this $f$ is not defined at $x=-1$ and cannot be extended there, either.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. However, you said it has a 'well-defined limit' but there is no limit existing at $x = 1$? Thanks.

Comment: @Strikers Sorry, it's only a one-sided limit here, but still, $\lim_{x \to 1^+} f(x)$ exists (it's zero).

Answer (score 0):

Because $\sqrt{\frac{x^2-2x+1}{x^2-1}}=\sqrt{\frac{(x-1)^2}{(x-1)(x+1)}}=\sqrt{\frac{(x-1)}{(x+1)}}$ and the later is existing at $x=1$

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. Okay, I see that, but without the factoring and simplification, and you use direct substation it yields $\sqrt{\frac{0}{0}}$ and that would be invalid. Why is that not considered?

Comment: You'll get $0$ in the denominator if $x=-1$ (In the last square root)

Comment: No, $f$ is technically not defined at $x=1$.

Comment: Yes, so why is it that the function does not exist at $x = -1$ but not at $x = 1$ when they both yield division by zero?

Comment: @Strikers aha, does not exist or it's not defined when the denominator yields $0$

Comment: @Isabella So you are saying there is a difference between "does not exist" and "is not defined"?

Comment: @Strikers Yes, there is. I think in this case the correct would be "not defined" because you have division by $0.$